# RoyalSlider HTML content only appears on first slide on iPad

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I am using RoyalSlider on a Wordpress build to create the home page slider. Everything is working perfectly, except when I viewed the site on an iPad today.

The slides are using the HTML content field to generate the text that floats over the images. On all the browsers I've tested, other than Safari on iPad, everything's working fine.

On the iPad, the text appears on the first slide. Then when it slides to the next slide, the text does not appear, and somethings will flash for a brief second during the animation.

Has anyone experienced something like this before? If so, any suggestions how to resolve this?

Here's a link to the site:
http://pilgrim.quantumdynamix.net/

Comment: That's a premium plugin for which we don't have access to the code. Have you tried their support channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering hardware acceleration on your element over slider, e.g.;

```
.rsSliderText {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```